# PHP: Website getting hacked weirdly

Tags: php, html, security, code-injection

I'm currently developing a web interface in PHP/HTML for a Database course project.

Basically, there is an input field :

`<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">`

that allows one to search for things in my DB.

Yesterday evening, after uploading my new index.php, I refreshed the page and there was (was I though it was) some sort of Injection because my page was entirely filled with spam ("YO MAMAYO MAMAYO MAMA etc,").

I secured the form using the "`htmlspecialchars()`" php function. And once again, I just uploaded the new index.php just 10 mins ago and the page was filled with "YO MAMA" right after I refreshed.

Has anyone an idea about that ? And how can I check/secure my page ?

Thanks

EDIT : The code of the form is the following :

```
<div id="searchbox"> 
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
   Query database : <input type="text" id="field" name="query">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search!">
</form> 
</div>
```

and I just secured with :

```
if(isset($_POST['query']) && !empty($_POST['query'])) {
    $param = htmlspecialchars($_POST['query'], ENT_QUOTES);
...
```

The inputs I can give are anything, the goal is to search for people or events or etc.
I only have a database class file which I include in my index.php

EDIT2 :
Sql query is the following :

```
SELECT p.idParticipant As id, a.name AS name, c.countryName AS country,
count(g.idGame) AS countGames 
FROM Athlete a, Country c, Game g, Participant p, Event e
WHERE a.idAthlete = p.fkAthlete 
AND p.fkCountry = c.idCountry 
AND p.fkGame = g.idGame
AND g.idGame = e.fkGame 
AND a.name LIKE '%$param%' 
GROUP BY a.name 
ORDER BY a.name;
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to use `real_escape_string` function (with mysqli or PDO), I would change FTP password AND database user and password.

Answer (score 0):

Whitelist you input let say if only string is allowed use is_string() to verify it.

Comment: trying using htmlpurifier to validate user input.

Answer (score -1):

Use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [parameterized queries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). Stop creating queries by concatenating input.

And stop using the mysql_* set of functions. Right now. Every time you type it in a php source file, $deity kills a kitten. Stop this slaughter please.